# React-admin SimpleForm does not call PUT request when click save

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In react-admin, SimpleForm should automatically call PUT request, however it does not work. Instead, for some odd reason, it's calling GET request whenever I click the save button. I'm new to react-admin and I've been looking around for solutions but I have no idea what's wrong. I have tried calling PUT request with postman and it works, so I know for sure that my backend is not the problem.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';
import createAdminStore from '../createAdminStore';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';

import { 
    CategoryList, 
    CategoryShow, 
    ItemList, 
    ItemShow,
    ItemEdit
 } from '../adminComponents/posts';

const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://localhost:3000/api');
const history = createHashHistory();

const AdminContainer = () => (
    <Provider store={createAdminStore({dataProvider, history })}>
        <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} history={history} title="My Admin">
             <Resource name="categories" list={CategoryList} show={CategoryShow} />
            <Resource name="items" list={ItemList} show={ItemShow} edit={ItemEdit}/>
        </Admin>
    </Provider>
);
```

Here's Item Edit component:

```
export const ItemEdit = props => (
    <Edit {...props} >
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput disabled source="id" />
            <TextInput source="name" />
            <TextInput source="description" />
            <NumberInput source="price" />
            {/* <TextInput source="selections" /> */}
            <ReferenceInput source="category_id" reference="categories">
                <SelectInput optionText="name" />
            </ReferenceInput>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

Comment: Does it work if you don't wrap the admin with a `<Provider>`? Because that's not necessary in your case.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be related, but I just resolved this issue using react-admin 3.7. I've got an Edit component wrapping a SimpleForm, and when I removed the onSuccess attribute, the form started working again.